# Excel - Create new rows in table2 based on a value in table1

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with three spreadsheets.

Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3 are linked together with a unique identifier.

Sheet1 can only have 1 instance of each unique identifier; however, sheet2 and sheet3 can have multiple instances.

Assume the Unique ID begins in Table1 A2:A541. I would like a column next to it (B2:B541) that when a number is entered it copies that unique ID to sheet2 in column A the number of times designated.

```
Sheet1 Column A
ID
2023_0001
2023_0002
2023_0003

Sheet1 Column B
Copy_to_Sheet2
2
3
2

Sheet1 Column C
Copy_to_Sheet3
3
2
2
```

This would copy the ID 2023_0001, 2 times to Sheet2 as new rows, and 3 times to Sheet3

Is this possible?

I'm not terribly familiar with VBA syntax, but I have tried a few other solutions from Google. I'm just not sure how to adjust them to fit my needs.  This one works, but I don't want to worry about prompts. I'm trying to make this as easy for my employees as possible.

```
Sub CopyData()
Updateby Extendoffice
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = OutRng.Range("A1")
For Each Rng In InputRng.Rows
    xValue = Rng.Range("A1").Value
    xNum = Rng.Range("B1").Value
    OutRng.Resize(xNum, 1).Value = xValue
    Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(xNum, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a prompt, you could just put the code as a Worksheet_Change event rather than writing a separate module. Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 2 Then
    NoCopy = Target.Value
    CopyVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Target.Row, 1)
    x = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For y = 1 To NoCopy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x + y, 1) = CopyVal
    Next y
ElseIf Target.Column = 3 Then
    NoCopy = Target.Value
    CopyVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Target.Row, 1)
    x = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For y = 1 To NoCopy
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x + y, 1) = CopyVal
    Next y
End If

End Sub
```

You'd need to put it in 'Sheet1' in Microsoft Excel Objects rather than a module but then it would just work as people added to columns B and C. I've assumed there will be a value in Column A before B or C